# Implementing ListView with a horizontal scroll in Android

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

Is there a way to implement List View in Android, with a horizontal scroll? I've come across this library: https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView . I'm wondering if there's a native way of doing it. I want to implement something similar to Amazon's android app's horizontal Scroll view on Home screen. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for [this](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) , let me know if it helps.

Comment: The demo looks fine. I'll integrate with my app and see if it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, now in new versions of Android(Lollipop) you can implement horizontal listviews using new [RecyclerView](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/first-glance-androids-recyclerview/) library.

This can help you.